# How to paginate twitter data to show 100 or more latest tweet?

Tags: json, twitter, analytics

I am new to PowerBI environment. And got this source code from some sources to create a search parameter and to show latest tweet about several keywords. The problem is, the latest data shown in PowerBI only accumulated to the latest 7 days' tweet. How to generate the latest data from last 1 months or years? Thanks.

Here is the code
/*
This M script gets an bearer token and performs a tweet search from the Twitter REST API
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only
Requires establishing a Twitter application in order to obtain a Consumer Key & Consumer Secret
https://apps.twitter.com/

```
IMPORTANT - The Consumer Key and Consumer secret should be treated as passwords and not distributed
*/

let
     // Concatenates the Consumer Key & Consumer Secret and converts to base64
     authKey = "Basic " & Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary("XXXAPITOKENXXX"),0),
     url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
     // Uses the Twitter POST oauth2/token method to obtain a bearer token
     GetJson = Web.Contents(url,
         [
         Headers = [#"Authorization"=authKey,
                    #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"],
         Content = Text.ToBinary("grant_type=client_credentials") 
     ]
 ),
 FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
 // Gets token from the Json response
 AccessToken = FormatAsJson[access_token],
 AccessTokenHeader = "bearer " & AccessToken,
 // Uses the Twitter GET search/tweets method using the bearer token from the previous POST oauth2/token method
 GetJsonQuery = Web.Contents("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q="&SearchParameters&"&count=100",
     [
         Headers = [#"Authorization"=AccessTokenHeader]
     ]
 ),
 FormatAsJsonQuery = Json.Document(GetJsonQuery),
 NavigateToStatuses = FormatAsJsonQuery[statuses],
 TableFromList = Table.FromList(NavigateToStatuses, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
 ExpandColumn = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(TableFromList, "Column1", {"metadata", "created_at", "id", "id_str", "text", "source", "truncated", "in_reply_to_status_id", "in_reply_to_status_id_str", "in_reply_to_user_id", "in_reply_to_user_id_str", "in_reply_to_screen_name", "user", "geo", "coordinates", "place", "contributors", "is_quote_status", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "entities", "favorited", "retweeted", "lang", "possibly_sensitive", "quoted_status_id", "quoted_status_id_str", "quoted_status"}, {"Column1.metadata", "Column1.created_at", "Column1.id", "Column1.id_str", "Column1.text", "Column1.source", "Column1.truncated", "Column1.in_reply_to_status_id", "Column1.in_reply_to_status_id_str", "Column1.in_reply_to_user_id", "Column1.in_reply_to_user_id_str", "Column1.in_reply_to_screen_name", "Column1.user", "Column1.geo", "Column1.coordinates", "Column1.place", "Column1.contributors", "Column1.is_quote_status", "Column1.retweet_count", "Column1.favorite_count", "Column1.entities", "Column1.favorited", "Column1.retweeted", "Column1.lang", "Column1.possibly_sensitive", "Column1.quoted_status_id", "Column1.quoted_status_id_str", "Column1.quoted_status"})
in
    ExpandColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

The v1.1 search API only provides access to the past 7 days of Tweets. You will need to use a different API to retrieve data from further back:

- the [premium API 30-days or full-archive search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/search-api/api-reference/premium-search) (these are commercial but have a free tier for limited access)

or

- the [v2 full-archive search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start/full-archive-search) (this requires that you have an account that is on the [Academic Research product track](https://developer.twitter.com/en/solutions/academic-research/products-for-researchers))

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have premium search API access, then by passing parameter **toDate**, **fromDate** and **maxResults** you can get your desired paginated data.

Doc for reference [Twitter Search API Document](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/search-api/api-reference/premium-search#Pagination)